# What is the best way to implement JWT-authenticated API calls in react-native, without having to include the header's Authorization in each fetch?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have tried to find a suitable pattern and modules from various articles, but I can't find **ONE** single approach where the header options are injected from a user token stored in the redux store. A pattern where you have to include the Authorization parameter in each api-call is not a good code structure. See example below.

```
 async _getProtectedQuote() {
  var DEMO_TOKEN = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
  fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/protected/random-quote", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + DEMO_TOKEN
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((quote) => {
    AlertIOS.alert(
      "Chuck Norris Quote:", quote)
  })
  .done();
},
```

Comment: You will need to send your Authorization header each call - if not - your API will need to allow unauthenticated requests.

You could try to create a method in your class called `setToken` which sets a internal variable `token`. In your `_getProtectedQuote` you would use that internal `token`. Now you need to run the `AsyncStorage.getItem` just one time on startup and run the `setToken` method once with your result.

Comment: Generally you use a middleware to centralise this, so you dont repeat this everywhere right? You can create a middleware that funnels all your api requests, where the jwt is appended.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution where I create an API interface based on the apisauce module. By exposing its setHeaders() method and injecting that into the redux-logic middleware, I am able to fetch the stored idToken and set the header in the authentication-process for future api-calls. Any changes to idToken made by e.g. a token-refresh makes sure to update the api-header accordingly.